# Using Split() in Python to pull all the quotes out of a string

Tags: python, split

So what I'm trying to do is use python to parse through articles on pull all the quotes. I used beautiful soup to pull the html from the site, now I'm trying to use split to print everything that is in quotes.

For example, go from:

```
I like quotes but especially "have problems"
```

to go to

```
have problems
```

Answer (score 2):

Or `re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"',s)`, demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='I like quotes but especially "have problems"'
>>> re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"',s)
['have problems']
>>>
```

`regex` is your clear friend,

> https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html
>
> > https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.findall

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the list returned by `str.split`:

```
s = 'I like quotes but especially "have problems" and "need more quotes"'
s.split('"')[1::2]
```

This returns:

```
['have problems', 'need more quotes']
```